# Compacting If-Then-ElseIf

Tags: excel, vba

any good tip to compact the following code in Excel VBA?
I am trying to set gridlines in my chart (major and minor) but that depends on the maximum value of the source data.
Appreciate the inputs! (from a newbie)

```
    If MaxY < 0.1 Then
        MajGridY = 0.1 / 5
        MinGridY = 0.1 / 10
    ElseIf MaxY < 1 Then
        MajGridY = 1 / 5
        MinGridY = 1 / 10
    ElseIf MaxY < 10 Then
        MajGridY = 10 / 5
        MinGridY = 10 / 10
    ElseIf MaxY < 100 Then
        MajGridY = 100 / 5
        MinGridY = 100 / 10
    ElseIf MaxY < 1000 Then
        MajGridY = 1000 / 5
        MinGridY = 1000 / 10
    ElseIf MaxY < 10000 Then
        MajGridY = 10000 / 5
        MinGridY = 10000 / 10
    ElseIf MaxY < 100000 Then
        MajGridY = 100000 / 5
        MinGridY = 100000 / 10
    ElseIf MaxY < 1000000 Then
        MajGridY = 1000000 / 5
        MinGridY = 1000000 / 10
    ElseIf MaxY < 10000000 Then
        MajGridY = 10000000 / 5
        MinGridY = 10000000 / 10
    ElseIf MaxY < 100000000 Then
        MajGridY = 100000000 / 5
        MinGridY = 100000000 / 10
    End If
```

Comment: Use `Select Case` instead... it will be much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Dim factor As Long

If MaxY < 1 Then
  factor = Fix(Application.WorksheetFunction.Log10(MaxY))
Else
  factor = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Application.WorksheetFunction.Log10(MaxY), 0)
End If

If 10 ^ factor = MaxY Then factor = factor + 1
  
MajGridY = 10 ^ factor / 5
MinGridY = 10 ^ factor / 10
```

Comment: This works great. I still need years of practice to get to this answer :-)
Very minor edits to last 2 lines, but the concept stays:

```
MajGridY = 10 ^ factor / 100
MinGridY = 10 ^ factor / 200
```